# Why doesn't the :from parameter work on my Rails actionmailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I followed a tutorial for sending email in Rails, and I have this in my production.rb

```
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :tls            => true,
    :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port           => 587,
    :domain         => 'http://myapp.heroku.com',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => 'mygmailusername@gmail.com',
    :password       => 'mypassword'
  }
```

And this Actionmailer

```
mail(
     :to => user.email,
     :from => "noreply@myapp.heroku.com",
     :subject => "Welcome to My App",
     :body => "Please activate your account by going to this address: \n" +
              "http://myapp.heroku.com/" + 
              user.username + "/activate/" + user.activation_key
     )
```

When it sends an e-mail, the e-mail comes from mygmailusername@gmail.com instead of from noreply@myapp.heroku.com. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, GMail does let you send mail as somebody else (for the obvious reason).